# Load content in a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'm getting some problem using jquery. I hav a series of cards with an href attribute that call a php page and sends the attribute with the get method. Here's an example

```
    <div class="pers_genres_card">
<div class="card-panel teal_green">
    <span class="white-text"><a class="pers_href_white" target="_self" href="generatorgen.php?genre=Blues">Classica</a></span>
</div>
<div class="card-panel teal_orange">
    <span class="white-text"><a class="pers_href_white" href="generatorgen.php?genre=Blues">Blues</a></span>
</div>
```

Now I have a central div where i want to load the result of my php script without page refreshing. This is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.pers_href_white').click(function(){
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#central').load(page);
        return false;
    }
    });
});
```

But when I try to click on the href, the results are shown in another page. In few words the jquery script doesn't start, so the classical href attribute load. I have already written another jquery script that works perfectly, also more complex than this script, i can't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: You have syntax errors, so your javascript probably doesn't run at all, and when you click an anchor, it redirects, as it's supposed to do. Learn how to use your console and debug simple syntax errors, like not properly closing a function.

Comment: You need to prevent the propagation of the click event so it doesn't load a new page. `click( function ( e ) { e.preventDefault(); } )`.

Comment: As @hungerstar says, you need to properly cancel the native click event. The `return false` is not doing that and can be removed and replaced with the code shown in the comment above.

Comment: @ScottMarcus - Why wouldn't `return false` do that, it's `preventDefault` and `stopPropogation` rolled into one ?

Comment: @adeneo Is it? I didn't realize that. I was thinking in "vanilla" JavaScript.

Comment: In jQuery it is, and `stopPropogation` won't help either when it's in the event handler for the anchor itself.

Comment: Stupid question but do you have a `central` div?  Also, if you press f12 and click on the console tab, do you have any errors?

Comment: @Pete, yes with another jquery script i already load another page in this central div, but clicking on one element of this div the new jquery script doesn't work

Comment: ok so this new link is dynamically loaded? if so you want to have a look at event delegation

Comment: @Pete sorry I can't understand what you are saying, these are my first times using jquery

Comment: Did the link exist at the the time the page loaded?  Or did you ajax the link in after?  If you dynamically loaded the link, then you need to look at this: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 1):

When you click the link the browser will just redirect to it. You have to actively prevent the browser from doing that. You can use the DOM method [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for that.

Change your JS to the following and it should work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.pers_href_white').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#central').load(page);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: JQuery doesn't provide `event.preventDefault()`. That's part of the standard DOM API. (https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#dom-event-preventdefault) Also, according to @adeneo, `return false` in JQuery accomplishes this.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Never knew that. It's part of the JQuery API doc (https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). I'll edit the post.

Comment: jQuery has it's own events and callbacks, so yes, it has it's own `preventDefault` -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Comment: @AlessioCorvaglia what does not work? What's the error?